# travis ci bad decrypt in windows 10

Tags: travis-ci

when I try push.
the travis ci failed.

```
bad decrypt

140356638541472:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:532:
The command "openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_b5321099e062_key -iv $encrypted_b5321099e062_iv -in id_rsa.enc -out ~/.ssh/id_rsa -d" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

what should I do?

Comment: If you can, please provide a link to the build log. Otherwise, please try and provide a minimal test case in a public repository displaying the error you experience.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known [issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4746) by the Travis team. Possible solution seems to be to encrypt the file in a virtual machine with a Linux on it. This is a one shot deal.

Comment: An alternative would be to encrypt your file directly with openssl. See this [last section on this page](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/#Using-OpenSSL).

Comment: If you've got Vagrant installed, you can use this Vagrantfile which creates & encrypts a new deploy_key: https://gist.github.com/Argelbargel/022270d7ffdf7316e2811a7f7dbea81c

Comment: @lpcarignan Your link needs to be lowercase, apparently https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/#using-openssl